# I'm struggling to upload users to my user Database on Access

Tags: java, database, ucanaccess

I'm trying to save users into my user database on access and I'm met with this error every time

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT user lacks privilege or object not found: USERS

I've insured there are no syntax errors in the code or Query I hope someone could help me sort this out

here is the class

```
public void UserUpload(RegisterUserModel registerUserModel) throws Exception
        {
    
         try
            {
             Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
             Statement s=conn.createStatement();
             String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Firstname, Surname, Email, Password) VALUES ('" +RegisterUserModel.name  + "','" + RegisterUserModel.surname + "','" + RegisterUserModel.email + "','" + RegisterUserModel.password + "')"; 
             s.executeUpdate(sql);
             while(rs.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    }
            } 
         
            catch(SQLException e)
             {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
         
        }
 

        
public void update(String ud)throws Exception
{
    try 
        {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(ud);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
            {
            System.out.println("Cannot updte the database");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Check the permissions on the database. Did you give the credentials write permissions?